# Could Not Resolve the Method "hasElementId"

Tags: php, magento-1, magic-getter

I am confused about this method declaration. In this class Wrapper.php (Mage/Page/Block/Html/) under _toHtml() method, there is a line coded as below.

```
$id = $this->hasElementId() ? sprintf(' id="%s"', $this->getElementId()) : '';
```

Which class defined this method **hasElementId()**? I tried to search current class and all parent class, none of them are declared this method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No class defined that.  Magento model objects and block objects all have "magic" methods implemented via PHP's `__call` method (defined on `Varien_Object`).

There are magic `get`, `set`, and `has` methods.  That means you can set data on a block or model (or any object that inherits from `Varien_Object`) with the following.  Follow along with the comments below

```
//assuming we're inside a block or model object
class Package_Module_Block_Some extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    //...
    public function someMethod()
    {
        //if you try to get something that hasn't been set, you'll get null
        var_dump ( $this->getSomeValue() );

        //so lets set it, and try again          
        $this->setSomeValue('Foo Bar');
        var_dump( $this->getSomeValue() );

        //then there's the has method
        if($this->hasSomeValue())
        {
            var_dump( 'The data value some_value (SomeValue) exists');
        }
        else
        {
            var_dump( 'The data value some_value (SomeValue) does not exists');
        }

       if($this->hasSomeOtherValue())
       {
           var_dump( 'The data value some_value (SomeValue) exists');
       }
       else
       {
           var_dump( 'The data value some_value (SomeValue) does not exists');
       }
    }
    //...
}
```

So long as you don't define a method with the same name, you can use the methods prefixed with `set`, `get`, and `has` to set, get and check for the existence of data properties on your object in Magento.

Comment: Appreciate Alan. Then how would I know all method names that created by magic methods? I assumed those properties (e.g: elementId) must be defined somewhere.

Comment: @Leongelis You don't.  It depends entirely on what data has, or has not, been added to to the object.  Try var_dump($this->getData()); to see all the data property, and then camel case the key names to get a list of magic methods.

Comment: I see. Alan, you kind help really mean a lot to everyone here. Greatly appreciate.